# How do I pipe data into an executable from within a PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, stdin, shell-exec

I have a binary that takes input from stdin that I use on the command line by piping file contents to it like `cat query.sql | go-mysql-format`, but how do I pipe a variable to the executable?

Currently I have

```
file_put_contents($File = "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/tmp/" . uuid(), $MySQL);
$o = shell_exec('cat ' . escapeshellarg($File) . ' | go-mysql-format --html');
```

Basically I would like to skip the file creation.

It's also important to note that the data will contain newlines, so I'm not sure wrapping the variable with `escapeshellarg` will be appropriate

Comment: Have a look at `proc_open` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: You'd have to give it a try, but doesn't something like `'echo ' . escapeshellarg($MySQL) . ' | go-mysql-format --html'` work?

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, that worked

Comment: @jeroen I'm not so sure what it's doing, I tried but it gives output as separate newlines or something, not sure if it's executing each line or what. I found the solution though, adding it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the point in the right direction from @NigelRen to look at `proc_open`

I wrapped the steps in a function for me to use later, which might be helpful.

```
function exec_stdin(string $Command, string $Data) {
    $_ = proc_open($Command, [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $p);
    if (is_resource($_)) {
        fwrite($p[0], $Data);
        fclose($p[0]);
        $o = stream_get_contents($p[1]);
        fclose($p[1]);

        $_ = proc_close($_);

        return $o;
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(exec_stdin('go-mysql-format', 'yeet'));
```

returns

```
string(7) "`yeet` "
```

which is exactly the output I needed!